# Refreshing data elements on refresh

Tags: php, html, database, page-refresh

how do I refresh data elements on refresh?

Right now the only way that I can refresh the data of a user is when they disconect:

//
I want to make it automatic that when they refresh the page it refreshes their data

```
    else if ($checkPwd === true) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["usersId"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $uidExists["usersName"];
    $_SESSION["usertel"] = $uidExists["usersTel"];
    $_SESSION["userpfp"] = $uidExists["usersPfp"];
    $_SESSION["userbanner"] = $uidExists["usersBanner"];
    $_SESSION["userrating"] = $uidExists["usersRating"];
    $_SESSION["userdescription"] = $uidExists["usersDescription"];
    header("location: ../MyAccount.php");
    exit();
}
```